# Exclude last check-in from publish/ release in TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Please help me.
I've to exclude last or 4th last check-in by another user from application publish/ release in azure devops(Team Foundation Version Control). And it is possible to publish from my local visual studio or l've to use azure release system.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish from your local visual studio. You can deploy your app to a folder, IIS, Azure, or another destination via from local visual studio. Please check the detailed steps in [this document](http://Deploy%20your%20app%20to%20a%20folder,%20IIS,%20Azure,%20or%20another%20destination).

For more information please check [Visual Studio deployment documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/?view=vs-2019).

You can also roll back your changeset to a prior one. Please check the detailed steps in document [Roll back changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/roll-back-changesets?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you for help. But one more thing actually i'm excluding the code because of client doesn't need latest changes and alter publish i need that excluded code later on. Our tester will test and publish with next publish.

Comment: @AbhilashKumar You can check the tutorials in above answer to deploy directly from visual studio? You can [accept above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if above document are what you were looking for.